# Convexity of certain objective polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

We know $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i^2$ is a convex polynomial if $a_i\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$ holds.

1. Is $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i^{2d}$ also convex at every $d\in\{1,2,\dots\}$ if $a_i\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$ holds?
2. Is $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i^{2d+1}$ also convex at every $d\in\{1,2,\dots\}$ if $a_i\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$ holds?

What is the easiest way to see this.

$\underline{Motivation}:$ I want to maximize polynomials $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{2d}+M\sum_{j=1}^ma_jy_j$$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{2d}+M\sum_{j=1}^ma_jy_j^2$$ over a convex polytope where $M>0$ and $a_j\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$ are fixed and I want to know if these are convex since then the problem is in $P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is true by looking at the Hessian matrix (which is diagonal and has nonnegative coefficients). [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_several_variables) is a reference for convexity detection using the Hessian, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix#Eigenvalues) is a reference for checking positive semi-definiteness of your Hessian, and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Diagonal_matrix_example) is a reference for computing eigenvalues of a diagonal matrix.
2. Clearly, this isn't always true because with $n = 1$, $d = 1$, and $a_1 = 1$, $x^3_1$ is not convex.

You might more generally be interested in [sos-convexity](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/VaVmuri/images/4/41/AP09-cdc_s.pdf)

Comment: Could you provide proof of convexity of 1.?

Comment: @Turbo added more details. Can you take it from here?